# Gradle 'external dependencies' folder

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I need to add a jar as a dependency for my gradle project, and this dependency have another dependencies like a .so file and some data in a subfolder.
When I build it, it just get the jar, but not the other dependencies.

This is for a java 1.8 project with gradle 5.1.1

The structure that I have is:

```
/libs
  - dep.jar
  - dep.so
  / data
    - usedindep
    - usedindep.dat
    - alsousedindep.dat
/src ...
- build.gradle
```

my build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'superCoolProject.Program'
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dir 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include:'*')

    compile(name: 'dep')
    compile(name: 'dep', ext: 'so')
    compile(name: 'data/usedindep', ext: '')
    compile(name: 'data/usedindep', ext: 'dat')
    compile(name: 'data/alsousedindep', ext: 'dat')
}
```

The result is a jar with only 'dep.jar' added as dependency.
Is there a method to add a whole external folder as a resource for the project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    runtime fileTree('lib') { include '*' }
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: @Alucherdi Well if you add the data folder to your resources folder then that should be loading file, as for native library not exactly sure